# Pmetrics: declare default fortran compiler before calling PMBuild()

Tags: r, linux, docker, gfortran

We're trying to use an R-package called [Pmetrics](http://www.lapk.org/pmetrics.php)

This does normally not support a Linux environment but We'd like to perform some tests in a parallel setup. E.g. a distributed test with a 1000 runs distributed over 20 containers.

Using this Dockerfile you can reproduce the error.

```
FROM centos:centos7.5.1804
RUN yum -y install gcc-gfortran epel-release
RUN mkdir /root/pksim
RUN mkdir /root/pksim/Rlibraries
WORKDIR /root/pksim
RUN yum -y install R
COPY test.r test.r
COPY install.r install.r
```

the install.r script contains these lines

```
.libPaths("/root/pksim/Rlibraries")
install.packages("http://www.lapk.org/software/Pmetrics/Repos/src/contrib/Pmetrics_1.5.2.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```

The test.r script contains these lines

```
r = getOption("repos")
r["CRAN"] = "http://lib.ugent.be/CRAN/"
options(repos = r)
rm(r)
.libPaths("/root/pksim/Rlibraries")
library(Pmetrics)
PMbuild()
```

You can make this work using these commands:

- build the image: `docker build -t pksim .`
- run the image: `docker run -ti pksim /bin//bash`. A Console should appear.
- run the R install.r script (on the console): `Rscript install.r`
- run the R test.r script (on the console): `Rscript test.r` It gets stuck when it calls `PMBuild()`

When executing test.r, the process is stuck in an endless loop requesting this user input.

```
Pmetrics needs to know which Fortran compiler you are using.
You only have to specify this once.
However, you can reconfigure if your compiler changes
by using the command PMFortranConfig(reconfig=T).

In each of the following <exec> is a place holder for the executable file name
and <files> is a placeholder for the files to be compiled.  Both are required.
When applicable serial and parallel compile statements in Pmetrics are listed in that order.

1. gfortran -m64 -w -O3 -o <exec> <files>
    gfortran -O3 -w -fopenmp -fmax-stack-var-size=32768 -o <exec> <files>
2. g95: g95 -o -fstatic <exec> <files>
3. Intel Visual: ifort -o <exec> <files>
4. Lahey: lf90  <files> -fix -out <exec>
5. Other (define custom command)
6. Help, I don't have a Fortran compiler!

Enter the number of your compiler:

Enter the number of your compiler:

Enter the number of your compiler:

Enter the number of your compiler:

Enter the number of your compiler:

Enter the number of your compiler:
```

Is there a way to configure the default compiler by setting some option somewhere before running PMBuild()?

We've created a [GitHub](https://github.com/SofieDhaese/pksim) repo containing the sources for this problem.

Can anyone think of a workaround?

Comment: @VladimirF, is this better?

Comment: Yes, I hope so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file `~/.config/Pmetrics/FortConfig.txt` can be created with the contents:

```
gfortran -m64 -w -O3 -o <exec> <files>
gfortran -O3 -w -fopenmp -fmax-stack-var-size=32768 -o <exec> <files>
```

In case you want to use the 1 proposed compiler.

Comment: For those interested, we also needed to load the Pango and cairo linux libraries because a console environment does not have X11 devices.